# BSD box running PFSense reports weird disk capacity

Tags: bsd, pfsense

So I have a BSD box running PFSense.  I was alerted to some potential problems when using the web interface, where a warning appeared saying:

```
Warning: fopen(/tmp/config.lock): failed to open stream: Device not configured in /etc/inc/util.inc on line 127 Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /etc/inc/util.inc on line 138 Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /etc/inc/util.inc on line 139 Warning: session_start(): open(/var/tmp//sess_16403a4a095178a6015e436a1f8dea0f, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) in /usr/local/www/csrf/csrf-magic.php on line 321
```

When I `ssh` to the box, everything appears fine, except this weird output from `df -h`:

```
#: df -h -i

    Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity iused ifree %iused  Mounted on
    /dev/ad6s1a    443G    316M    407G     0%    6.8k   60M    0%   /
    devfs          1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%       0     0  100%   /dev
    /dev/md0       3.6M     44k    3.3M     1%      22   744    3%   /var/run
    devfs          1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%       0     0  100%   /var/dhcpd/dev
```

I'm assuming here that the hard drive is probably toast; nothing else really accounts for this weird "Capacity: 0%".

Am I correct in that assumption, or is it possible something else is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The Capacity means the amount of file living on the disk in percentage. as you can see only 316MB of 443G is used right now. if you sure this info is wrong. check it with couple of other tools too.
then you could perform a sanity check on your partitions to look for errors.
either way this is no definitive way to ascertain what you asked from the information you provided.
but according to [this](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=h4d5q1uenmvbqls7khc7npvn37&topic=52422.msg280152#msg280152) pfsense forum entry there is a good chance your hard is failing.

Comment: Well, it says `Capacity: 0%` which is obviously not correct if 316 of 443 MB is in use

Comment: @Siler what I meant was " You couldn't infer hard failure just by that alone but it is a sign to investigate."